# Change GraphQL Variables param dynamically from function value

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I am using a function in reactjs that will return a GrpahQL query result. My code is following

```js
...
const fetchData = async (url, query, param, variable) => {
        return await axios.post(url, {
            query: query,
            variables: { param: variable }
        })
    };
...
```

I want to change the param of `variables` dynamically from the function value.

How can I pass the `param` to variables?

Comment: you mean like so `{ [param] : variable }` ... computed property ?

Comment: Works like a charm. please post it as an answer. I will tick mark on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are looking for

> computed property names in Object [MDN DOCS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#syntax)

so it would be something as

```
{ [param] : variable }
```

so now `param` refers to some variable value instead of "param" as a string